# Maximum Students Taking Exam Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing the "Maximum Students Taking Exam" algorithm.

Given an m * n matrix seats that represent seat distributions in a classroom. If a seat is broken, it is denoted by '#' character otherwise it is denoted by a '.' character.

Students can see the answers of those sitting next to the left, right, upper left, and upper right, but he cannot see the answers of the student sitting directly in front or behind him. Return the maximum number of students that can take the exam together without any cheating being possible.

Students must be placed in seats in good condition.

My solution: I loop the matrix if I find a good seat ".", I check left, right, upper left, and upper right to see if there is another student (avoid cheating). If not, I increment my answer and set this seat as occupied.

```js
var maxStudents = function(seats) {
  let ans = 0;
  if (seats === null || seats.length === 0) return ans;

  for (let i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++) {
      if (seats[i][j] === ".") {
        if (seatStudent(seats, i, j)) {
          seats[i][j] = "S";
          ans++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return ans;
};

const seatStudent = function(seats, i, j) {
  if (j + 1 < seats[i].length && seats[i][j + 1] === "S") return false;
  if (j - 1 > 0 && seats[i][j - 1] === "S") return false;
  if (i - 1 > 0 && j + 1 < seats[i].length && seats[i - 1][j + 1] === "S")
    return false;
  if (i - 1 > 0 && j - 1 > 0 && seats[i - 1][j - 1] === "S") return false;

  return true;
};
```

For the input:

```
seats = [["#",".","#","#",".","#"],
         [".","#","#","#","#","."],
         ["#",".","#","#",".","#"]]
```

The answer should be 4. However, I'm getting 5. I can't understand why it is returning 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i-1 > 0)
```

should be

```
if(i-1 >= 0)
```

done.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I didn't see it.  However, if I try with the input: [["#",".",".",".","#"],[".","#",".","#","."],[".",".","#",".","."],[".","#",".","#","."],["#",".",".",".","#"]]. My solution returns 6 and the correct answer should be 10

Comment: keep testing. make sure you are changing ALL of the `>0` to `>= 0`

Comment: I did! I think I need to use dfs.

Comment: add tons of console log statements to find out where it is going wrong. this is pretty simple stuff.

Comment: I think they way we are thinking about it is wrong. I found this online: https://zxi.mytechroad.com/blog/dynamic-programming/leetcode-1349-maximum-students-taking-exam/